# Errors with writing WordPress function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, responsive-design

So, I'm trying to write a custom function in WordPress for displaying the featured_image with picturefill and srcset, to display different sizes of the `feat_img`. I've dont a lot of themeing but, not so much writing functions.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

is enabled in my `functions.php`. I'm also requiring a file that has my code:

```
function responsive_featured_img() {

if ( function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
    $feat_small = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'small' );
    $feat_med = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );
    $feat_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' ); ?>


<img src="<?php echo $feat_small[0]; ?>"
    srcset="<?php echo $feat_large[0]; ?> 1024w, <?php echo $feat_med[0]; ?> 400w, <?php echo $feat_small[0]; ?> 320w"
    sizes="100vw"
    alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" 
/> 

<?php } } ?>
```

So, this is actually working inside my WordPress template, but getting a lot of errors. Like so:

```
    Notice: Undefined variable: post in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Bass/wp-content/themes/Bass/inc/responsive-img.php on line 13

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Bass/wp-content/themes/Bass/inc/responsive-img.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: post in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Bass/wp-content/themes/Bass/inc/responsive-img.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Bass/wp-content/themes/Bass/inc/responsive-img.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined variable: post in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Bass/wp-content/themes/Bass/inc/responsive-img.php on line 15

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Bass/wp-content/themes/Bass/inc/responsive-img.php on line 15
```

Any ideas would be great!

UPDATE:
After input from Howlin, this code is working error free. I'm sure it could maybe be re-factored:

```
function responsive_featured_img() {
global $post;
if ( function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
    $feat_small = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'small' );
    $feat_med = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );
    $feat_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' ); ?>


<img src="<?php echo $feat_small[0]; ?>"
    srcset="<?php echo $feat_large[0]; ?> 1024w, <?php echo $feat_med[0]; ?> 400w, <?php echo $feat_small[0]; ?> 320w"
    sizes="100vw"
    alt="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"
```

to

```
alt="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>"
```

You get the error you are getting when you try use something like `the_title();` outside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Using the code I suggested above should fix this.

EDIT: Adding `global $post;` before the if statement will fix the errors. You were calling `$post->ID` but since that function is outside the loop that error was thrown.

Comment: Hmmm, that may be more WP proper, but it did not get rid of any of the errors. The function IS still working however! Cheers

Comment: What exactly are lines 13/14 and 15?

Comment: 13: $feat_small = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'small' );
14: $feat_med = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );
15:$feat_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' ); ?>

Comment: I'm confused why i'm getting errors for these? Kind of thought I was defining those variables in this instance?

Comment: If you try add `global $post;` before the if statement, will that make any difference?

Comment: Actually, yes! That got rid of all errors. Thank you! Ill post final code here

Comment: @szyam no problem, it's because `$post->ID` was tying to call the post id outside the loop and since it wasn't set it was throwing the errors, adding `global $post` would fix those errors.